# Why raycast in Unity doesn't work when close to an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am wondering what could cause this situation. I am raycasting from camera (on the object I am moving with mouse) to the pallet. When the pallet is close enough the rays become red, which means they are hitting something. My task is check if there is a something between the camera and the pallet. Please explain me how it works.

[GIF visualising my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F0Zm.gif)

Part of my code:

```
bool[] hits = new bool[aug_pts.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < aug_pts.Count; i++)
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            bool hit;
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, aug_pts[i]);

            Vector3 direction = aug_pts[i] - this.transform.position;
            hit = Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, direction, out hitInfo, distance);

            if (hit && hitInfo.collider.name != "wood_pal") 
            {
                Debug.DrawLine(this.transform.position, aug_pts[i], Color.red);
                hits[i] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                hits[i] = false;
                Debug.DrawLine(this.transform.position, aug_pts[i], Color.green);
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem. The question my be closed. Rays were hitting an object, which is with the camera. Correction needed is:

```
if(hit && hitInfo.collider.name != "wood_pal" && hitInfo.collider.name != "my_object")
{
...
}
```